# List<String[]> method Adding always same values

Tags: java, arraylist

In my Java Project, i want to read values from txt file to List method.Values seems like;
1 kjhjhhkj 788
4 klkkld3 732
89 jksdsdsd 23
Number of row changable. I have tried this codes and getting same values in all indexes.
What can i do?

```
    String[] dizi = new String[3];

    List<String[]> listOfLists = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    File f = new File("input.txt");

    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            int i = 0;
            while (s.hasNext() && i < 3) {
                dizi[i] = s.next();
                i++;
            }
            listOfLists.add(dizi);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Dosyaya ba?lanmaya çal???l?rken hata olu?tu");
    }
    int q = listOfLists.size();
    for (int z = 0; z < q; z++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            System.out.print(listOfLists.get(z)[k] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: better use `List<List<String>>`

Comment: try s.nextLine() instead of next. see the diff b/n next() in nextLine() here :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String [] dizi = new String [3];
```

dizi is a global variable getting overridden eveytime in the loop. Thats why you are getting same values at all indexes
 Make a new instance everytime before adding to the list.

Comment: if this solves your problem then mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You put the same reference to the list, create a new array in while loop.

```
while (s.hasNextLine()){

   String[] dizi = new String[3]; //new array

   int i = 0;
   while (s.hasNext() && i < 3)
   {           
       dizi[i] = s.next();
       i++;                
   }
   listOfLists.add(dizi);
}
```